# How to set a variable in command prompt through python?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I'm trying to do the speech recognition with Google API and I got the transcript successfully already in the command prompt. However, I want to do the same thing in Python IDLE and the error I got is "Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application." I circumvent this issue in the command prompt by `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='C:\\Users\\...\\PSC.json'` and it worked. So how do you set this variable through python IDLE? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `os` module.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'C:\\Users\\...\\PSC.json'     # Set a new env. variable (String value)
>>> os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')       # Retrieve the value
'C:\\Users\\...\\PSC.json'
```